# JQuery: replace DIV contents with html from an external file. Full example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

**Question**

What's the full code to enable jQuery on a page and then use it to replace the contents of a DIV with HTML text from an external file?

**Background**

I'm brand new to jQuery and I'm eager to work with it so I can learn it.  I have a site where I need to replace the contents of the same div (a footer) that exists on every page.  Fortunately, each of these pages already imports the same header file.  So I'm going to modify that header file with some jQuery magic! I'm having trouble finding ***full examples*** and I figured other's might have similar questions. Who better to ask than the SO gurus?

**Example**

Given a basic HTML file `Example.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="selectedTarget">
            Existing content.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And an external file `includes/contentSnippet.html` containing a snippet of html:

```
<p>
    Hello World!
</p>
```

What would the new `Example.html`file be that would link the proper jQuery libraries (from the ./js directory) and replace the div's contents via jQuery?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ok, I'll bite...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#selectedTarget').load('includes/contentSnippet.html');
           });
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="selectedTarget">
            Existing content.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notes:

1. I've linked the jquery libraries directly from jQuery's public CDN (which is [allowed and encouraged](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery))
2. You can find the documentation for jQuery's `load()` function [right here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: Your wording kinda made it sound like there's something wrong with that method?

Comment: I'm also curious to know if this is an extremely bad idea or something. I'd like to do something similar but "I'll bite" tells me that noone has really done this for some reason... Any elaboration on that?

Answer (score 2):

To use jQuery on your page, it's generally recommended to place the script before the closing body tag to keep the rest of the page's content from being blocked to load. It's also recommended to use the code from the Google CDN for various benefits 
Here are some helpful links: http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/ and http://encosia.com/2010/09/15/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/.

jQuery Tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // your script will go here
</script>
</body>
```

To replace the content of the `div` with content from another file, this is done with an AJAX request:

```
$('#selectedTarget').load('includes/contentSnippet.html');
```

Obviously there is a lot to learn and much more ways to control and optimize your pages. I would definitely recommend reading the jQuery API documentation to learn more: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: did you mean, "it's generally recommended to place the script ***right before*** the ***closing*** body tag . . . "

Comment: I read through your link but I don't see any mention of using the Google CDN. Would you say using google is preferred even above loading it locally from your own server?

Comment: Here are some helpful links: <http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/> and  <http://encosia.com/2010/09/15/6953-reasons-why-i-still-let-google-host-jquery-for-me/>.

Comment: And yes, I would always prefer using the Google CDN over self-hosting jQuery. Read the links to see why.