# Optimum way to insert external html content HTML5 compliant? php vs HTML5 vs javascript methods

Tags: php, javascript, performance, html

I know how simple this probably seems to you gurus, but I have been searching for over an hour to no avail...

Goal:  Use a single footer file and menu file for all my webpages.  Taking into account blocking, speed, etc.  The content of my menu is pure html/css and the content of my footer is pure html/css.  Would the optimal solution change based on the content being injected?  e.g.  If videos, jscript, etc. were involved.

Two part question:
1)  Which method is optimal?  Some kind of php include, using the  tag, using jscript, etc.
2)  How precisely is this achieved keeping HTML 5 standards?  i.e.  For the php method to work, does my calling webpage need to be .php and then does that make the HTML5 standard a moot point?  e.g.  If I want to inject footer.php into index.html, does my index file also have to be .php?  Similarly for the  tag, can the external file be an .html file(I don't like the idea of reloading all the header information with .css calls) or should it be .php?

Within the index.html file I have tried the following:

```
<object id="footerArea" width="100%" height="20%" 
  type="text/html" data="footer.html">
</object>
```

and

```
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Neither of these seem to work for me.

In case you are wondering...  Here is the code for my footer I am trying to inject with sample data to make it shorter and easier to read:

```
<div class="footer box">
<p class="f-right t-right">
 <a href="#">www.mysite.com</a><br />
  Address: Medford, OR<br />
  Phone: (541) 555-5555
</p>

<p class="f-left">
 Copyright &copy;&nbsp;2011 <a href="#">My Name</a><br />
</p>

<p class="f-left" style="margin-left:20px;">
 <a href="http://sampleurl.com" target="_blank">
  <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
   src="http://sampleurl.com"
   alt="Valid CSS3!" />
 </a>
</p>

<p class="f-left" style="margin-left:20px;">
 <a href="http://sampleurl" target="_blank">
 <img src="http://sample.png" width="228" height="50" alt="sample alt" title="sample title">
 </a>
</p>
</div>
```

Please excuse my formatting.  I am still new to posting code in forums.  I tried my best :)

Comment: You said: "Neither of these seem to work for me".  Can you tell us *how* they didn't work?  Specifically, the PHP approach is probably the right direction... so, what error did you receive? What did the page look like? When you "view source" in your browser, is the footer code visible there, or is your footer area just empty?

Comment: Sorry for lack of detail about my particular error.  When I used the object which injected footer code shown, none of the styles applied to it which made me realize that in order to use the object tag to inject the footer I would have to call again to the same page the appropriate css files.  My code is not as it should be for the object tag to work the way I intended which was optimally (not having to create the html tags with css called in header).  Was looking for a way to call the server files once only such as the css and have it apply to everything on page including dynamic content.

Comment: When I tried the php include, I just had blank space on my page where the footer should be.  There was no sizing for it or anything.  When I inspect the code it shows the php include statement commented out.  my php file is the exact code above with an opening tag '<?php' closing tag '?>' and 'echo' in front of every line except opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension of a filename you seen in a url has absolutely **NOTHING** with how that file will be treated by a browser when it's downloaded. It all comes down to the `Content-type` header that accompanies the file. A webmaster can trivially configure their server to treat all `.exe` files as plain HTML pages. They can also tell the webserver to run `.html` pages through the PHP parser. In fact, with "modern" SEO-optimized urls, you rarely see a file extension at all. It'll all be things like `example.com/some/wonky/path`, not `example.com/page.php?id=wonky`.

The fact that PHP has built and output a page also has nothing to do with HTML compliance. It comes down to whether the page the browser receives conforms to the standards. Are all tags properly closed? Attributes properly defined? Tags properly nested? Blah blah blah.

If you've built your code properly, the html that's output will be properly structured and be valid html. If it's not valid html, that's not PHP's fault - that's your fault for putting together code that doesn't produce the proper output.

The only time a file extension in a URL **MIGHT** be relevant is if the webserver outputs a generic content-type, e.g. "application/octet-stream". The browser MAY use a detectable file extension to guess at the content's type and try to treat it as such. But this is not guaranteed nor reliable.

Comment: Before I attempted to inject the footer and nav menu, the page was 100% HTML5 and css3 compliant according to the validation website I used.  It was only then that I decided to take the footer and nav menu into separate files so I wouldn't have to update all my other pages whenever I decide to make updates.  Thank you very much for the helpful info though.  Never thought about 'content-type' headers from the server.  I do have php working for other applications on different sites, but same server.  If that would even apply based on your info.

Comment: So even though I didn't get much input to which way is optimal, your info seems to be the most helpful.  To answer one of my own questions on HTML5:  My index.html needed to be an index.php in order for the 'include' statements to work and it checks out as HTML5 compliant according to validater site.  A side note for optimization, I would think a solution which allows injected content to be cached if used on other pages or utilize a single template page with dynamic code injected and URL's changed depending on content user is viewing (seo).

Answer (score 1):

This is what a [PHP include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) should look like:

```
<?php include 'footer.php'?>
```

As far as I can see the code you have in your question is assigning the string "footer.php" to the variable `include`.  However, rather than rolling your own template system, have you considered using something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

If the called code like for a footer that is canned, you might want to create the simple footer like you want then include:

```
<?php
readfile("yourfile.htm");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do what you want:

**index.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <!-- other css, scripts etc -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- your main content here -->
    <?php include 'footer.html' ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**footer.html**

```
<div class="footer box">
  <!-- your footer content here -->
</div>
```

when you load index.php in the browser, and "view source", you should see the contents shown above, but the `<?php include "footer.html" ?>` should be replaced with the content from the file "footer.html".

You should *not* see the php code itself when you view source through the web-browser.  If you do see php code in "view source", this indicates that your server isn't configured to run php properly.

---

For an alternate approach, which loads the content from the browser, and which doesn't use php, I'll point you to [this related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125254/jquery-replace-div-contents-with-html-from-an-external-file-full-example/5125319#5125319).

Comment: Yeah was pretty dumb of me to have the improper include statement.  I changed it to '<?php include 'footer.php' ?>' but it still shows as commented out when I inspect on site.  My php form on the same site works just fine.  I uploaded a new php file, ran '<?php phpinfo( ); ?>' and it displays my php info just fine.