# html not showing javascript code inserted

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

thanks for reading this post, I am trying to add a menu to a website, but I want to do it with a script, the problem is the page is not showing anything I don't know what I am doing wrong, here is how I am calling the function

```
<head>
<link href="../css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<script src="../includes/menu.js"></script><!-- end .header --></div>
<div class="content">
</body>
```

and the js file is here

```
<Script Language="JavaScript">
document.write("<div id='cssmenu'>\
<ul>\
<li class='active'><a href='homeuccgestion.php'><span>Inicio</span></a>         </li>\
<li><a href='nuevoformato.php'><span>Prestamos</span></a></li>\
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Consultas</span></a>\
<ul>\
<li><a href='consultas.php'><span>Movimientos</span></a></li>\
<li class='last'><a href='editar_instrumento.php'><span>Inventario</span>  </a></li>\
</ul>\
</li>\
<li class="has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Edici&oacute;n</span></a>\
<ul>\
<li><a href='editar_unidad.php'><span>Unidades</span></a></li>\
<li><a href="editar_usuarios.php">Usuarios</a></li>\
</ul>\
</li>\
<li><a href='contacto.php'><span>Contacto</span></a></li>\
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Apartar Prestamo</span></a></li>\ 
</ul>\
</div>\
\    
\
");
</Script>
```

this is some of the css code

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
width:990px;
height: 49px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
background: #141414;
}
```

thanks in advance any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: why do you want javascript to add a menu, when its just hardcoded html?

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to do this than with `document.write`, which is generally considered archaic.

Comment: If you are using external js, then no need for `<script>` tags inside js file

Comment: @depperm The reason I want to add javascript is to make the code look clean, so then I just need to import the script and handle the menu in a different file

Comment: @Keerthi if I don't add the script tag throws error, however it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @isherwood could you tell me which way? thanks

Comment: Not without some context.

Comment: The script tag is causing an error and stopping your script from being executed.

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking at server-side templating engines, or maybe SSI (server-side includes). Using raw JavaScript for templating isn't a great idea.

Comment: @m69 even though I remove it, the situation does not change

Comment: That's because there are genuine code errors in the script that are being reported.

Comment: For that matter, load jQuery and use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125254/jquery-replace-div-contents-with-html-from-an-external-file-full-example

Comment: @isherwood so better do it with php?, because the menu will be the same for almost every page, so I just want to replicate it

Comment: The 11th line of you code has a double quote in it; that is the error.

Comment: The 18th line has a space after the backslash.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll review all these errors and report what happens

Comment: @m69 did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, just remove the script tag, fix the double quotes, and remove the spaces after the backslashes. (The moral of the story is: use something like php for this kind of thing.)

Comment: Use the console in your browser's developer tools; it'll show you all the javascript errors in detail.

Comment: @m69 I couldn't find the errors, I moved it to php :(, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` just writes in the body.

if you want to add HTML via script, first made up that HTML properly in a String variable, like,

```
var html = '';
html += '<div id='cssmenu'>'
     +    '<ul>'
     +      '<li class='active'><a href='homeuccgestion.php'><span>Inicio</span></a></li>'
     + ..................
     +     '</ul>'
     +   '</div>' ;
```

Now when your HTML String is ready, add it to wherever you want to show it,

```
document.getElementById("myMenuElement").innerHTML = html;
```

and your HTML should have the id **myMenuElement**

```
<head>
  <link href="../css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="../includes/menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">      
      <div id="myMenuElement"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

If this is not what you wanted, let me know in comments and I will update my answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like that is what I need, I'll try it out and tell you what happens THANKS!

Comment: Welcome @Juancadiyjohndiy

Comment: would you recommend doing this with php or js?

Comment: @Juancadiyjohndiy, If the html is really large, doing it with php will be a better idea, in my opinion. But it entirely depends upon what the developer is trying to achieve. :)