# How to import DIVs from external HTML file to another html using JQUERY (with saving their original form)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, import

I searched for inserting some divs (it's business partners carousel) into html code. I need to do this because when amount of articles increase nobody will be willing to correct content on every single html page - instead of doing this there will be only one file to make changes in.

Here I found how to do it with jquery which I was already using:
[JQuery: replace DIV contents with html from an external file. Full example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125254/jquery-replace-div-contents-with-html-from-an-external-file-full-example) and I'm importing content of this file http://forumnarzedziowe.pl/test/partnerscarousel.html
with

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#selectedTarget').load('../partnerscarousel.html');
       });
    </script>
```

Script is working and importing, which is great but as you can see on http://forumnarzedziowe.pl/test/krotko/StackOverflowExample.html
imported divs are not "elegant".

I tried importing different parts and the result is unfortunately always the same.

Comment: Have you tried adding `display:inline-block` to the CSS for `.item`?

Comment: Thanks @sideroxylon for fast reply - after your comment I tried, but all it's making is that images are becoming overlap.

Comment: How would you like to display them? now it's just a matter of CSS.. or you need them to slide too?

Comment: thanks @miguelmpn for your interest - I improved look of that example page. Now there are two sliders - 
1) embed in the code
2) imported with jquery (not sliding)

Comment: The classes are different, the javascript slider is not applying, I think that is the problem. If the CSS classes are the same they will have the same behaviour as the top on

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to look through the code on your website, but was unable to find the code that ran the carousel. Often what is the problem with dynamically loaded html elements is that your jquery functions are applied to the DOM before you have loaded this new element. This means that your dynamically loaded HTML will not have the carousel functionality attached to it when you load it into the DOM. I would recomend adding an onload function to your js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#selectedTarget').load('../partnerscarousel.html', function (e) {
          // Attach carousel code to this
       });
   });
</script>
```